# Dynamically set header values in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-gateway

## Question

What are the necessary steps to dynamically set headers in the response from API gateway using the context from the authorizer response.

### Current Approach

Here are the current steps I have implemented to set the response header(s) dynamically.

1. Dynamically generate the response header value in the authorizer-lambda and return it in the context of the authorizer response.

```js
return {
    principalId,
    policyDocument: {
      Version: "2012-10-17",
      Statement: [
        {
            Action: "execute-api:Invoke",
            Effect: effect,
            Resource: this.resource(this.event.path),
        },
      ],
    },
    context: {
      dynamicValue: dynamicValue
    },
};
```

2. Configure the gateway response headers. (NOTE: This is where I an running into issues.)

   - API Gateway → [Choose Gateway] → Gateway Responses → Unauthorized
   - Add Response Header:

     - Response Header: `x-new-header-value`
     - Value: `$context.authorizer.dynamicValue`

### Problem(s)

When using the [mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) for the value in the step above I get the error below. This makes me think I am missing a configuration step.

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: $context.authorizer.doLogout]
```